# Is there a javascript event when a user right clicks on a photo to copy it?

Tags: javascript, image, clipboard

I was experimenting with the clipboard api and when a user copies text or a selection this event will fire:

```
document.addEventListener('copy', function(e){
  //Do something
});
```

I notice when the user right clicks an image and chooses 'copy image' or 'copy image url' the event won't fire. Is there a way to fire the event when this happens.

Comment: there is no event when that happens, so no.

Comment: not to mention that clipboard api is not consistent cross browser